# Failing 2 tests in bracket,braces, paranthesis matching

Tags: c, parsing, stack

Was trying to get all the test cases to pass but I keep getting either very few or a lot of  test cases wrong depending on the test case. I have a feeling like I am missing something major but after countless hours I still have no idea what I am missing.

Test case:
12 is the number of strings followed by the strings
Empty line is the first string to be tested.

```
12

([])
(([()])))
([()[]()])()
(([()])
([])
(([()])))
([()[]()])()
(
(]
)(
][
```

Expected output:

```
Yes
Yes
No
Yes
No
Yes
No
Yes
No
No
No
No
```

My output:

```
Yes
Yes
No
Yes
Yes // should be no
Yes
No
Yes
Yes // should be no
No
No
No
```

Failed cases:

```
([])
(
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"


void ClearKeyboardBuffer(void) {
    char c;
    int noc;
    noc = scanf("%c", &c);
    
    while (noc == 1 && c != '\n') {
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }
}

Boolean isMatch(void) {
    STACK hStack;
    int noc;
    char c;
    Boolean m = TRUE;
    
    hStack = StackInitDefault();
    if (hStack == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate space for stack object.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    noc = scanf("%c", &c);
   
    
    while (noc == 1 && c != '\n') {
        if (StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
            if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{') {
                StackPush(hStack, c);
            } else if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}') {
                m = FALSE;
            }
        } else if (!StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
            if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{') {
                StackPush(hStack, c);
            } else if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}') {
                if (c == ')' && StackTop(hStack, NULL) == '(') {
                    StackPop(hStack);
                } else if (c == ']' && StackTop(hStack, NULL) == '[') {
                    StackPop(hStack);
                } else if (c == '}' && StackTop(hStack, NULL) == '{') {
                    StackPop(hStack);
                } else {
                    m = FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
        noc = scanf("%c", &c);
    }
    
    return  m;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    STACK hStack;
    int n;
 
    hStack = StackInitDefault();  // initialize the object
    if (hStack == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate space for stack object.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    scanf("%d", &n);  // get number of strings that the user will be inputting
    ClearKeyboardBuffer();
    
    while (n--) {
        if (isMatch()) {
            printf("Yes\n");
        } else {
            printf("No\n");
        }
        while (!StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
            StackPop(hStack);
        }
    }
    
    StackDestroy(&hStack);
    
    return 0;
}
```

stack.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"
#include "status.h"


struct node;
typedef struct node Node;

struct node {
    char value;
    Node* next;
};

struct stack {
    Node* head;
};
typedef struct stack Stack;

STACK StackInitDefault(void) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    
    if (pStack != NULL) {  
        pStack->head = NULL;
    }
    
    return pStack;
}
    
Boolean StackIsEmpty(STACK hStack) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    
    return (pStack->head == NULL)?TRUE:FALSE;
}

char StackTop(STACK hStack, Status* pStatus) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    
    if (StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
        if (pStatus != NULL) {
            *pStatus = FAILURE;
        }
        return 'e';
    }
    if (pStatus != NULL) {
        *pStatus = SUCCESS;
    }
    return pStack->head->value;
}


Status StackPush(STACK hStack, char c) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    
    temp->value = c;
    temp->next = pStack->head;
    pStack->head = temp;
    
    return SUCCESS;
}

Status StackPop(STACK hStack) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    Node* temp;
    
    if (StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    
    temp = pStack->head;
    pStack->head = pStack->head->next;
    free(temp);
    
    return SUCCESS;
}

void StackDestroy(STACK* phStack) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)*phStack;
    Node* temp = pStack->head;
    
    while (pStack->head != NULL) {
        temp = pStack->head;
        pStack->head = pStack->head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(pStack);
    
    *phStack = NULL;
}
```

stack.h

```
#ifndef stack_h
#define stack_h
#include "status.h"


typedef void* STACK;

STACK StackInitDefault(void);

Status StackPush(STACK hStack, char c);

Status StackPop(STACK hStack);

char StackTop(STACK hStack, Status* pStatus);

void StackDestroy(STACK* phStack);

Boolean StackIsEmpty(STACK hStack);



#endif /* stack_h */
```

status.h

```
#ifndef STATUS_H
#define STATUS_H

enum status { FAILURE, SUCCESS };
typedef enum status Status;

enum boolean { FALSE, TRUE };
typedef enum boolean Boolean;

#endif
```

Comment: Look carefully at #5. Notice that processing to the end of the line will leave one "open" on the stack. The code needs to test if the stack is empty at this point in the input. If the stack is not empty, then there's an unbalanced collection of characters on that line...

Comment: @bluediager Could you explain why this line "(([()])))"  is correct?

Comment: @Fe203 Oh gosh you are right I missed that simple case. Just fixed it and everything is working flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: @bluediager And what is the purpose of these definitions  enum boolean { FALSE, TRUE };
typedef enum boolean Boolean; while header <stdbool.h> already defines true and false?

Comment: "_flawless_"... Until you process a Lisp file and run out of heap storage... It's very good that `StackPush()` checks the return code from `malloc()`. Not so good that the return code from `StackPush()` is ignored by its caller. `:-)`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I believe it is wrong. It is string #7 and it is a "No."

Comment: @bluediager It is the second string.

Comment: @Fe2O3 You are right, I was just trying to do get it to work and pretending it is a void function without utilizing the return. I will be editing the code to utilize the return:)

Comment: @bluediager This declaration typedef void* STACK; just does not make sense. You already have struct stack {
    Node* head;
};

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You are right. I have no idea honestly. I believe string #2 is the same as string #7 yet #2 is a yes and #7 is a no.

Comment: @bluediager And the stack defined in main hStack = StackInitDefault(); is not even used. The used stack is the stack defined in isMatch

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am honestly not sure. I do agree that a lot of the things seem a bit pointless but the professor is really old school and he wants us to practice treating the stack object as an opaque object. It isn't the way I would make this program personally but it is the way he wants us to do it.

Comment: @bluediager Either your professor does not understand that an opaque type need not be represented as a `void *`, or they've done a poor job communicating that fact to you. Both are cause for concern.

Comment: Is the `void *` required? In `stack.h`, you could do: `typedef struct stack *STACK;`. This typedef is a _forward_ declaration of a pointer to a `struct stack`. Since you do _not_ define it in `stack.h`, but only in `stack.c`, only functions in `stack.c` can dereference/utilize the struct contents. Then, you can change/simplify (e.g.) `Status StackPop(STACK hStack) { Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack; ... }` to `Status StackPop(STACK pStack) { ... }` This provides opacity _and_ type safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments have largely covered all the issues here, but I will try to summarize.

The primary issue is, in order for an expression to be balanced, the stack should be checked to be *empty* after the expression has finished being parsed. This is not being done in your code.

A secondary issue is that your expectations for some of the test cases appears wrong (e.g., expecting `Yes` for `(([()])))`).

---

Other issues include:

The `STACK hStack;` in `main` and the `STACK hStack;` in `isMatch` are not the same object. The object in `isMatch` is never passed to `StackDestroy`, whereas the object in `main` is pointless.

One of the most prevalent issues is that there is quite a bit of repetition in this code. Constructs such as

```
if (StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
    /* ... */
} else if (!StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
   /* ... */
```

are overly verbose. The branch condition can be implied by just an `else` statement.

The entire push & pop section of `isMatch` spends a lot of time checking unnecessary or redundant conditions. Really, there's only a couple of things to do for every character in the expression

- Given an opening character (`(`, `[`, `{`), push it to the stack.
- Given a closing character (`)`, `]`, `}`), if the stack is empty, or the top of the stack is not the associated *opening character*, return an *invalid* result.

You are effectively working in terms of *lines* of input, but have done so by reading one character at a time from standard input. At the very least, one might suggest `getchar` instead of using `scanf("%c", ...)`, but it would be remiss not to mention the possibility of reading an entire line with `fgets`, and then processing it as *string*. As long as your lines aren't *extremely* long, this is very simple.

---

Some clearly *class/course/instructor/professor*-specific critiques, taking into account this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77348054/failing-2-tests-in-bracket-braces-paranthesis-matching#comment136359616_77348054):

> I am honestly not sure. I do agree that a lot of the things seem a bit pointless but the professor is really old school and he wants us to practice treating the stack object as an opaque object. It isn't the way I would make this program personally but it is the way he wants us to do it.

Both of these are basically noise:

```
enum status { FAILURE, SUCCESS };
typedef enum status Status;

enum boolean { FALSE, TRUE };
typedef enum boolean Boolean;
```

Both enumerations can easily be represented by the `bool` type: `true` and `false` have been available since C99, through [`<stdbool.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types) (and C23 will make them [keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bool_constant)).

This `typedef`

```
typedef void* STACK;
```

is not great. `void *` is not required to facilitate an opaque type. An opaque type is essentially just a pointer to an [*incomplete type*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type#Incomplete_types) (an identifiable type with no definition, i.e., information about its size). For an opaque type, your header could simply contain

```
typedef struct stack Stack;
Stack *StackInitDefault(void);
```

with the definition of `struct stack` in the source file.

Additionally, `typedef`-ing a pointer is somewhat contentious, but the most common advice is to avoid doing it. On-top of this, the explicit casts of a `void *` to another pointer type are not required, as a `void *` can be *implicitly* converted to any other pointer type.

(*If your compiler is complaining, you are probably using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.*)

Again, do whatever you need to do to pass the class, but some of these requirements are not good practices.

---

Here is an implementation that follows much of the advice laid out above. It avoids `typedef`-ing all together. `StackTop` is not present as it is not needed. It simply checks all lines of input (instead of a set number of lines derived from the first line), or it runs present test cases.

Some typical edge-cases: passing a null pointer to any library function, or popping an empty stack are both [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), and `StackDestroy` leaves its argument as a [dangling-pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) for the caller to deal with (mimics `free`).

Example usage:

```
$ ./a.out tests
"" -> PASS
"([])" -> PASS
"(([()])))" -> PASS
"([()[]()])()" -> PASS
"(([()])" -> PASS
"(([()])" -> PASS
"(([()])))" -> PASS
"([()[]()])()" -> PASS
"(" -> PASS
"(]" -> PASS
")(" -> PASS
"][" -> PASS
```

```
$ ./a.out 
[]
"[]" true
({[]})
"({[]})" true
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { puts("Hello world!"); }
"int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { puts("Hello world!"); }" true
)()(((){}{})()
")()(((){}{})()" false
```

The code:

`stack.h`:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

struct stack;

struct stack *StackInitDefault(void);
bool          StackIsEmpty(struct stack *);
bool          StackPush(struct stack *, char);
char          StackPop(struct stack *);
void          StackDestroy(struct stack *);

#endif
```

`stack.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

struct node {
    char value;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct stack {
    struct node *top;
};

struct stack *StackInitDefault(void)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof (struct stack));
}

bool StackIsEmpty(struct stack *s)
{
    return !s->top;
}

bool StackPush(struct stack *s, char c)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);

    if (!n)
        return false;

    n->value = c;
    n->prev = s->top;
    s->top = n;

    return true;
}

char StackPop(struct stack *s)
{
    struct node *n = s->top;
    char value = n->value;

    s->top = n->prev;
    free(n);

    return value;
}

/* slightly inefficient being written in terms of `StackPop`,
 * but keeps things simple */
void StackDestroy(struct stack *s)
{
    while (!StackIsEmpty(s))
        (void) StackPop(s);

    free(s);
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "stack.h"

#define stringify(b) ((b) ? "true" : "false")

/* running out of memory renders this program useless
 * bail out, let the OS clean up */
static void fatal_memory(void)
{
    fputs("CRITICAL: Out of memory.\n", stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static char invert(char c)
{
    switch (c) {
        case '(': return ')';
        case '[': return ']';
        case '{': return '}';
    }

    return '\0';
}

static bool is_balanced(const char *data)
{
    struct stack *st = StackInitDefault();

    if (!st)
        fatal_memory();

    for (char c; (c = *data); data++) {
        switch (c) {
            case '(':
            case '[':
            case '{':
                if (!StackPush(st, c))
                    fatal_memory();
                break;
            case ')':
            case ']':
            case '}':
                if (StackIsEmpty(st) || invert(StackPop(st)) != c) {
                    StackDestroy(st);
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    bool result = StackIsEmpty(st);

    StackDestroy(st);

    return result;
}

static void do_basic_testcases(void)
{
    const struct {
        const char *string;
        const bool expect;
    } tests[] = {
        { "",             true  },
        { "([])",         true  },
        { "(([()])))",    false },
        { "([()[]()])()", true  },
        { "(([()])",      false },
        { "(([()])",      false },
        { "(([()])))",    false },
        { "([()[]()])()", true  },
        { "(",            false },
        { "(]",           false },
        { ")(",           false },
        { "][",           false }
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof tests / sizeof *tests; i++) {
        bool expect = tests[i].expect;
        bool actual = is_balanced(tests[i].string);

        printf("\"%s\" -> ", tests[i].string);

        if (expect == actual)
            puts("PASS");
        else
            printf("FAIL: `%s` expected, got `%s`\n", stringify(expect), stringify(actual));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1 && 0 == strcmp("tests", argv[1]))
        do_basic_testcases();
    else {
        char line[4096];

        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
            printf("\"%s\" %s\n", line, stringify(is_balanced(line)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3 `PASS` does not indicate validity, but rather that the test cases behaved as expected.

Comment: Oops. Misinterpreted "PASS"... My bad... :-)